# How to print third largest element in an array?

Tags: c++, structure

I have two test cases, but only one of them is giving me correct output.
The second is giving me the first element of the array.
Please tell me where am I going wrong.
Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void thirdLargest(int arr[], int arr_size)
{
  int m1 = arr[0], m2 = arr[0], m3 = arr[0], i;

  for(i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
  {
    if(m1 < arr[i])
    {
      m3 = m2;
      m2 = m1;
      m1 = arr[i];
    }
    else if(m2 < arr[i])
    {
      m3 = m2;
      m2 = arr[i];
    }
    else if(m3 < arr[i])
    {
      m3 = arr[i];
    }
  }

  cout << "The third Largest element is " << m3;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int a[n];

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cin >> a[i];
  }

  thirdLargest(a, n);

  return 0;
}
```

Test cases:

```
TEST CASE 1 

INPUT
6
1 14 2 16 10 20
OUTPUT
The third Largest element is 14

TEST CASE 2 

INPUT
7
19 -10 20 14 2 16 10
OUTPUT
The third Largest element is 16
```

Comment: Both test cases seem to be correct, no?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)..

Comment: @Chelmy88 he specified the expected outputs, not the actual outputs

Comment: "The second is giving me the first element of the array." How so. In TEST CASE 2, the first element of the array is 19 and the test outputs 16.

Comment: For help debugging your code, read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips.

Comment: Is sorting the array allowed?

Comment: `cin >> n;int a[n];` -- This is not valid C++.

Comment: `std::nth_element` sounds like a good thing to look at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial condition isn't correct.  By starting with all 3 max values initialized to the first entry of the array, you will hit corner cases where none of the rest of the array will meet the conditions to alter them.

For example, if your array starts with the max, then none of the conditions will ever trigger.  This happens because your initial condition is actually invalid for the rest of the logic.

One approach to fix is to set your 3 values to a *sorted* version of the first three values in the array.  Another would be to initialize them to `numerical_limits<int>::min` (as suggested in a comment), which would only have a corner case for arrays shorter than 3.  Another would be to track the initialized state of each value-holder and check that before the comparison.

Of course, the best answer is to use prewritten primitives.  @Jesper Juhl wisely suggests `std::nth_element` which will solve the problem directly.

If this is a homework assignment, you might try something like `std::set` to store the 3 largest values.  You'd only have to compare against the first entry, insert if larger, then erase the new first entry to keep the size == 3.

Comment: I don't think there is something wrong with his code. If the array starts with max, m1 will have its value all along the loop while m2 and m3 will change. what's wrong with that?

Comment: or `numerical_limits<int>::min` as initial value

Comment: @mangusta consider the Test case 2, none of the values is bigger than 19, so the code will never see 16 as being bigger than the initial value

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 ah right. it should be a sorted triple initially